# Combobox binding to different list on inherited form in Java

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, combobox

I have a form with a combobox that is populated and bind to a table in the database. (FormA)
I then derive FormB from FormA and I would like the combobox on the form to get different data from the parent class.
in the base class combobox, the query populating is "SELECT p FROM Party p"
in the derived class I would like it to be "SELECT p FROM Party p where p = :flg"
however, the combobox on the derived class keeps the same behaviour as the base class.
Any suggestions?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication9;

import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JList;

/**
 *
 * @author DEV
 */
public class FormA extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form FormA
     */
    public FormA() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

        entityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("10.0.0.3:1433;databaseName=BANK_DBPU").createEntityManager();
        partyQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Party p");
        partyList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : partyQuery.getResultList();
        cmbCUST_ID = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JComboBoxBinding jComboBoxBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJComboBoxBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, partyList, cmbCUST_ID);
        bindingGroup.addBinding(jComboBoxBinding);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(78, 78, 78)
                .addComponent(cmbCUST_ID, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 251, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(71, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                .addComponent(cmbCUST_ID, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(224, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        cmbCUST_ID.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                if (value instanceof Party) {
                    Party mec = (Party)value;
                    setText(mec.getPartyId());
                }
                return this;
            }
        });

        bindingGroup.bind();

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FormA.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FormA.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FormA.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FormA.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FormA().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    protected javax.swing.JComboBox cmbCUST_ID;
    protected javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager;
    protected java.util.List<javaapplication9.Party> partyList;
    protected javax.persistence.Query partyQuery;
    private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}


/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication9;

/**
 *
 * @author DEV
 */
public class FormB extends FormA{

    public FormB() {
        super();


        refreshCombo();
    }

    private void refreshCombo(){
        entityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("10.0.0.3:1433;databaseName=BANK_DBPU").createEntityManager();
        partyQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Party p where p.active = :flg")
                .setParameter("flg", false);

        partyList = partyQuery.getResultList();

    }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to recreating the binding for the combobox, which would probably require you to have a method which creates and returns the binding, that way, you can override the method

Comment: Btw, forget to mention, I'm new to Java. so if you could show me how to return and assign the binding it'd be real great.

Comment: Anyways buddy, I got the thing covered. followed your suggestion though. I will skip the data binding generated by netbeans and I'll write it myself (hate the generated code)